# Angular Unit Testing : How to unit test validation template driven form?

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing

I have the component code as below :

```
<form name="form" (ngSubmit)="f.form.valid && login()" #f="ngForm" novalidate>
   <div class="form-group" >
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" [(ngModel)]="model.username" #username="ngModel" required />
      <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" [(ngModel)]="model.password" #password="ngModel" required />
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary margin-top-10 no-shadow full-width"><span class="text-uppercase">{{ 'login' | translate }}</span></button>
       </div>
</form>
```

I tried the code below, but not working, always get failure result.

```
it('test invalid', () => {
  const hostElement = fixture.nativeElement;
  const username: HTMLInputElement = hostElement.querySelector('input[name="username"]');

  username.value = 'jhon';
  username.dispatchEvent(new Event('input[name="username"]'));

  fixture.detectChanges();

  let form = component.f.form.controls;
  expect(form.username.invalid).toBe(false);

});
```

Is there any suggestion code for unit test?

Comment: `let form = component.f.form.controls;`    what is in your `component` object because you are not defined in your code

Comment: @Aniketkale I add this `@ViewChild('f') f: NgForm;` in my login component. but still get error : undefined is not an object (evaluating 'component.f')

Comment: Can you provide your component code also?

Comment: Hi @Aniketkale this my component code : https://codeshare.io/aYnjLM